# Plugin Error: Plugin "Visual Paradigm SDE for IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition)" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

When I install the Visual Paradigm SDE for IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) plugin, it doesn't work. After installing it and closing and reopening Android Studio 4.2, I get the above error message. How do I use this plugin with Android Studio 4.2?

Comment: Seems plugin is not supported in Android Studio. You may contact plugin vendor.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using UML Generator instead

Comment: I use Visual Paradigm paid version, with IntelliJ Idea paid version. Even in there the Visual Paradigm plugin doesn't work. It crashes and the support can't fix it for weeks now.

Answer (score 1):

### To answer the original question

You have to install the full version of the related product before the plugin will function properly. This can be purchased over at https://www.visual-paradigm.com (a trial period is also available).

**If you prefer an alternative to this paid software and need to fully remove the plugin**

```
Note - Uninstalling the typical way will not work with this plugin.
```

**Trash the plugin file:**

> Visual_Paradigm_SDE_for_IntelliJ_IDEA_%28Community_Edition%29_1149.jar

```
Depending on the version of AS your plugin path may vary slightly.
```

**Located (on MacOS):**

> /Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Google/yourAndroidStudioVersion/plugins

**Located (on Windows):**

> C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\yourAndroidStudioVersion\plugins